# Can you reference a separate chart other than the one the strategy is applied to?

Tags: pine-script

Let's say I want a strategy on ABC company that only executed while SPY is above its 200 day moving average.

Is that at all possible?

Or maybe seeing deviations for companies that should move together. Like applying a strategy on V while taking into account the movement of MA.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

While you can't trade on two symbols from a single strategy, you can certainly use data from any number of symbols/timeframes to derive conditions in your strategy. You could include this `allowTrades` boolean as a condition in your strat:

```
f_security(_sym, _res, _src, _rep) => security(_sym, _res, _src[not _rep and barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])[_rep or barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]
allowTrades = f_security("AMEX:SPY", "D", close > sma(close, 200), false)
```

Because it uses only confirmed information (it doesn't repaint), it will change on the following day the condition changes.